# Popular listvies WindowsPhone com select no banco sqlite

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Não sei se existe essa funcionalidade em windows phone mais vamos lá.

Estou acostumado a trabalhar na parte web com gridview e datasource onde crio a gridview e ligo cada coluna com o retorno do banco(datasource) em cada coluna atraves de um dataReader. Gostaria de fazer o mesmo no windowsPhone tenho um listView e preciso fazer um select junto com where no banco(SQLITE) e o resultado popular o list view mais estou bastante enrolado.